# Python program to find maximum watiting time

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

Geek is organizing a carnival this summer in which he has called N number of students. He has also booked M number of buses with each of them having a capacity of C. The time of arrival of N students is given by an array arr where i'th index (1 ≤ i ≤ N) denotes the time of arrival of i'th student. Geek doesn't want his students to wait for too long. Find the smallest value of the maximum waiting time any student has to wait.

Waiting time is the difference between his arrival and bus departure.It is always possible to accomodate all the students.

Ex 1:
Input :
n = 4, m = 3, c = 3
arr = 5 3 7 8

Ouput :
1

Explaination :
He can fill first bus with 1 student arriving at time 5, so waiting time =0.
He can fill second bus with 1 student arriving at time 3, so waiting time =0.
He can fill third bus with 2 student arriving at time 7 and 8, so one student waits for 1 unit of time.

Example 2

Input :
n = 6, m = 1, c = 6
arr = 1 1 1 1 1 1

Output :
0

Explaination :
All the students can be filled in 1 bus, so waiting time is 0.

I wanted to write a code in python to solve this problem.
not able to figure out way to do this.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the code you're having trouble with

Comment: if you don't try the problem will not solve by itself. You should at least try to solve it, then post the code of what you have tried and what problems/error you found.

Comment: If Geek his first name or his last name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some strategy suggestions: look at the sorted list of times and look at all the possible ways to sub-divide them according to the number of buses you have. Then calculate the waiting time according to that subdivision and find which subdivision gives you the minimum time.

Example 1:

You have sorted times 3, 5, 7, 8. Let's say you subdivide like this: bus, 3, bus, 5, bus, 7, 8. That's 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 1 minute of wait time.

Let's look at another subdivision. Bus, 3, 5, Bus, 7, Bus, 8. That's 2 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 2 minutes of waiting.

Do this for all possibilities (maybe eliminate some obviously bad subdivisions like Bus, Bus, Bus, 3, 5, 7, 8) and look at the possibility that minimizes wait time.

Come back with your attempt at coding and have some more specific questions ready.